nominate long comment threads for movement to chat?
Several of the comment threads under this question are getting long (although I don't see anything problematic in their content). As a non-moderator, what is the recommended etiquette for this site in this situation?

leave my own comment suggesting that users move the comments to chat?
flag one of the last comments in thread (with a "something else" reason) to attract a moderator?
mind my own business?

(something else?)

A flag is automatically raised when 20 comments have been posted (including deleted comments). The question you asked about has 19 comments. So if you do nothing, it'll probably be flagged on its own pretty shortly.
That said, you certainly can raise a custom flag at any time. This is particularly helpful if the longer discussions are likely to go off the rails (insults, debate, excessive back-and-forth conversation), or already have. As a general rule, we really don't mind looking at flags; even if we ultimately resolve the flag without taking any action, it's usually good that at least one of us is aware of a potential problem. So while I wouldn't go nuts flagging everything, I certainly wouldn't discourage sending a flag when you think there's something we should maybe look at.
As for telling users to take it to chat: as far as I know, there is no easy way for users to create a chat room (other than by typing a string of back-to-back comments and prompting the dialog). On the other hand, if a mod has already created a chat room, you can remind users to use it (and warn them that we cannot move comments to chat more than once, so they might want to cut-and-paste into the chat room before their comment gets nuked).
By the way: if you care about your ratio of helpful flags, you should flag the post rather than a comment. We can mark “helpful” on the post flags even if we don’t delete anything, whereas there’s no way to do this on comment flags.

Regarding this question in particular: it's a bit of a mess because the question (in my opinion) should be heavily reformulated or else closed. As such, I am inclined to provide a little leeway to those who want to discuss it in the comments, since maybe they can salvage it or otherwise help the OP. For a better question, we would more proactively edit the useful clarifications into the answer (help doing this is always welcome), after which those clarifications are no longer needed (and can be flagged), and we can also nuke the answers-in-the-comments (help flagging these is always welcome). And that would organically help control the comment length.

@Fe2O3 ideally, users should not doing discussion on the comment thread though...

Yeah, that's really not how the SE model works. If you can improve an answer, post a comment. If you disagree with an answer, post a better answer. If you post a better answer and it doesn't get many votes....well, that's a feature not a bug.

I understand your opinion, however I don’t think we will ever agree. Though in fact, this thread is a good example of why we usually try to avoid long comment chains: they often consume much effort and lead to inflamed feelings but rarely resolve anything.

Re nuking: after the chat room is created, the discussions (which while technically shouldn't happen,  let's be realistic, they do) are supposed to continue in the chat room. If a comment gets nuked afterwards, it's also a feature and not a bug.
